# Javascript - Extracting a substring

Tags: javascript

I reached a dead end with a feature I want to implement on my app.
I have the following string that I want to perform my search on:

Yellow Warning of Rain affecting Scotland (Central, Tayside & Fife) : Clackmannanshire, Falkirk, Perth and Kinross, Stirling valid from 0000 Sat 3 Nov to 2359 Sat 3 Nov

I know how to perform a search for a sub-string using either the match or includes functions but what I really want to do is extract part of the sub-string, so in this case, what I want to extract is: "from 0000 Sat 3 Nov to 2359 Sat 3 Nov"

Can someone help me?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: extract a substring how exactly? Using indexes I'm guessing? Look into `substr()` and `substring` methods

Comment: `str.match(/from \d{4}.+$/)`?

Comment: var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);

or

var str = '#anotherdata=value#iamlookingforthis=226885#id=101&start=1';
var value = str.match(/#iamlookingforthis=(\d+)/i)[1];

alert(value);

Comment: CAn you provide an example of what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You could search for sup patern, like `'from'` and `'to'` and the other digits, and date values.

```js
var string = 'Yellow Warning of Rain affecting Scotland (Central, Tayside & Fife) : Clackmannanshire, Falkirk, Perth and Kinross, Stirling valid from 0000 Sat 3 Nov to 2359 Sat 3 Nov',
    sub = string.match(/from \d{4} \D{3} \d{1,2} \D{3} to \d{4} \D{3} \d{1,2} \D{3}/);
    
console.log(sub);
```

Comment: This didn't worked the way i wanted but i got the idea. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've accomplished it:

```
            var stringtest = "Yellow Warning of Rain affecting Scotland (Central, Tayside & Fife) : Clackmannanshire, Falkirk, Perth and Kinross, Stirling valid from 0000 Sat 3 Nov to 2359 Sat 3 Nov";

            var n = stringtest.indexOf("valid from");
            var res1 = stringtest.slice(n,stringtest.length);
            var m = stringtest.indexOf(":");
            var res2 = stringtest.slice(0,m);
            var string = res2.concat(res1);



            newDiv.innerHTML = string;
```

This is the result:

Yellow Warning of Rain affecting Scotland (Central, Tayside & Fife) valid from 0000 Sat 3 Nov to 2359 Sat 3 Nov